# Should I cut glass window film to size before applying?

Tags: glass

I'm waiting for my tinted window film to be delivered. Is there any benefit to cutting the film to the exact right size before applying it to the window ?

If the window edges are perfectly straight it seems easier to do it on a table, possibly with scissors instead of an exacto knife.

Comment: Measurements and cutting and placement need to be perfect if cutting first.  Measure trice and maybe repeat before cutting.

Comment: avoid measuring if you can, it's always better to template or trim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the videos I have seen show that the film is cut to size plus 2” or 5cm.

This is so when it is laid on, a tiny error of not quite straight is dealt with - the small amount of waste is better than the whole sheet.

Also the exacto knife can follow the glass edge easily and there is no ruler to slip.

But your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a better results if you cut it first. Get some construction paper and make an exact template. Then lay the template on top of your actual film and cut along the template line with an exacto knife.